# Saving byte array in PROGMEM instead of SRAM

Tags: arduino-uno, ethernet, progmem, sram

For an ethernet project I do, I need to store the Ethernet Shield's MAC address.
I store it like that:

```
byte mac[] = { 0x90, 0xA2, 0xDA, 0x0F, 0xE1, 0x85 };
```

That works OK, but in my project I need all the SRAM available, so every byte of memory is important. I've used the F() macro and PROGMEM everywhere, but I couldn't manage to store the MAC byte array in the PROGMEM.

How can I store it in PROGMEM? Is it even possible?

Comment: Try "const byte mac[] PROGMEM = { ... };" https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/PROGMEM

Comment: MAC addresses are usually configurable, so I'd rather store it in EEPROM.

Comment: Since the original question indicated the OP was having trouble accessing PROGMEM, s/he may also have problems with EEPROM. Could you perhaps expand your answer with a code snippet that illustrates how your suggestion would work?

Comment: As it stands, this would make more sense as a comment. But if you can address the OP's issue – how to store the MAC address outside of SRAM then it would be a good answer.

Comment: Related: *[Can I write to flash memory using PROGMEM?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/1260/can-i-write-to-flash-memory-using-progmem)* and *[Writing objects to PROGMEM](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/29503/writing-objects-to-progmem)*

Answer (score 2):

See [Putting constant data into program memory (PROGMEM)](http://www.gammon.com.au/progmem) for tips about putting stuff into PROGMEM. However personally I wouldn't get too excited about saving 6 bytes.

---

Example code:

*Declare data globally:*

```C++
const byte mac [6] PROGMEM = { 0x90, 0xA2, 0xDA, 0x0F, 0xE1, 0x85 };
```

*Get a copy for use into a temporary variable:*

```C++
  char foo [6];
  memcpy_P (foo, mac, sizeof foo);
```