# Writing objects to PROGMEM

Tags: memory-usage, progmem

A few days ago I encountered memory problems (SRAM shortage) on my Arduino. I've read a lot and fixed the problem, now I have around 900 bytes free in SRAM. However, I still have difficulties understanding and using `progmem`.

The user is allowed to create up to 10 programs (a program in my case is just some object storing the user's preferences). As I don't want to run out of SRAM, I planned to store them in `PROGMEM`.

Consider the following class:

```cpp
#define MAX_PROGRAMS 10
#define MAX_PREFS 10 

class Program
{ 
  public:
    Program(String name, Preference* prefs[]); // ctor

    String getName();
    static byte getNoOfPrograms();
    static Program* getProgram(byte idx);

  private:
    const String _name;
    static int _programCtr;

    Preference* _preferences[MAX_PREFS];
    static Program* _programs[MAX_PROGRAMS];
};
```

One notices that a program can store up to 10 preferences, hence, if the user decides to make 10 programs, each with 10 different preferences, we will definitely run out of SRAM.

**Therefore, can I store instances of the above `Program` class in PROGMEM if I define them as below?**

```cpp
const Program* const pgm PROGMEM = new Program(F("Test"), ...);
// ...
delete pgm;
```

*I presume this is possible since the whole object is `const` and could never be changed. I actually tried this and had no compiler errors, however, I was stumbled by the fact that the above two lines of code use 22 bytes of SRAM, when I expected it not to use any.*

In my case, **would it be better not to store the whole object in `progmem` but only its constant fields, and do the same for all constants in `Preference` ?** (i.e. change `const String _name` to `const char name[] PROGMEM;` etc.)

Comment: Are you aware that everything you store in `progmem` is going to be fixed *at compile time*? I ask because you wish to use `progmem` to store _user defined programs_, so that makes sense only if the user defines that programs _before_ compilation occurs... which to me makes the whole thing a nonsense... but I believe it all comes down to what is a _program_ for you...

Comment: @RobertoLoGiacco Wow, thanks! This indeed does not make sense if it is to be fixed at compile time, since, the user will make those programs at runtime. Does this imply that i can not avoid to run out of SRAM, apart from limiting the user to less programs and preferences?

Comment: Your example only puts the object pointer in program memory. "new" allocates the object from the heap. Please see this example that I put together a few years back. https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Sketchbook/tree/master/ProgramMemory

Comment: A more advanced example can be found in Cosa LCD Menu handler. The menu data structure is put in program memory; https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Cosa/blob/master/libraries/Menu/Menu.hh and example sketch, https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Cosa/blob/master/examples/LCD/CosaLCDmenu/CosaLCDmenu.ino

Comment: @MikaelPatel Right, i was not sure about dynamically allocating the object or not. Thanks for the examples, they are quiet useful, however, my `program` instances will be created at runtime. Hence, i think i will have no other option than limiting the user to a few programs..

Comment: @HyperZ Or cleaning up your system to a) not use `String`, and b) tokenize your program and store it as binary code.

Comment: It is possible for software running on the ATmega to write to program memory at runtime, and even to erase it in large blocks.  See bootloader sources for an example.

Comment: @Majenko Thanks, i cleaned up the whole system such that i don't use the `String` class anymore in order not to fragment the heap. Now, what do you mean by tokenizing my program and storing it as binary code? :)

Comment: I've marked this as a duplicate of [Using PROGMEM to store array of structs](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/13545/using-progmem-to-store-array-of-structs). The question isn't the same, but the solution is.

Comment: Related: *[Can I write to flash memory using PROGMEM?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/1260/can-i-write-to-flash-memory-using-progmem)*